# Run powershell from sql with diffrent credentials

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have some sql servers in active directory.
From them i am trying to run a powershell script that is physically located on
a remote machine.

The issue is that when i am running the xp_cmdshell script it is using 
the sql service user from the dc (domain\domainuser).

And it gives me the error: 
The argument \192.168.1.10\PS\myscirpt.ps1 to the -File does not exists.

If i am looking in event viewer on my remote server that has locally this Powershell script, i am getting a security error:
"log in failed for user (domain\domainuser)"

That why i need to run the script with the remote user and password

sql script:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe -file \\192.168.1.10\PS\Myscript.ps1 -ExectionPolicy Unrestricted'
```

By the way PS is a shared folder with full everyone read and write permissions.

I would like not using a network drive if it is possible, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy account can be created for use with this, however please be aware of the security implications that may arise from using an over-provisioned account.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190359.aspx

-Sean

Answer (score 0):

If you can install additional software, this might do the trick for you.

[Use RunAs utility to execute a program from command line or batch file using a different user account](http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/53.htm)

Comment: If i was one sever ok, but its not.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it via start-process and call powershell.exe and pass in a credential.

[start-process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx)